# Why asp.net generate Jquery version 1.3.2 NuGet has version 1.6,2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemodal

when I run the application, the system crushes because of a bug related to 
[Problems with simple modal in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499517/problems-with-simple-modal-in-ie9)

The problem is that, even though there was an update on JQuery, the system continue to genrate a file jquery-1.3.2.min.js and I don't know where this comes from.

Tried the configuration files or on the internet. The file jquery-1.6.2 is also generated.

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably being brought over by NuGet during update or it may also be coming from source control. I wouldn't worry about it, just reference the jquery version you want and that should be enough for you assuming the file is in your solution and the link is right.